# Rails dynamically generating input fields based on user attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, dynamic

I am creating a wedding site that has users(People who receive invitations) and guests(will attend as guests of users but have no email ect). Users are created with a maximum number of guests that they are allowed to bring and a food choice.  Guests only have a name and a food choice.  My associations are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guests
  has_one :food

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  has_one :food
end
```

I am using a form-backing object to handle validations on the RSVP form. it looks like:

```
class Rsvp
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
```

`<validations/ instances of variables to be saved/ collection of error messages / method to save fields ect.>`

My problem is that on the `/users/:id/rsvp/new` page(nested route) I want to generate as many forms for guests (With name and food choice) as the user's maximum number of guests (assigned on creation of the user). I know how to do it with accecpts_nested_attributes fields_for and

```
current_user.max_guests.times do
  @rsvp.guests.build
end
```

I want to avoid using this method because the naming of things gets confusing fast. Is there a way to generate the input fields some other way?

Comment: How many guests are you expecting each user to have as a maximum?

Comment: I would say that 6 would be at the high end.  I can get it to save a single object but I can't get it to save the multiple objects

Comment: You don't reply need a separate class for Guest as it could just call back to the User class using a separate column to store the association

Comment: but if the user has a unique email field how would a user have many guests?  Sorry if this is a dumb question I am a bit new to rails.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with your relationships. In class Guest replace 'belongs_to :users' with 'belongs_to :user' (singular) (that will be a one to many relationship). If many to many relationship is intended then 'belongs_to :users' still has to be replaced with 'has_many' or 'has_many ... through ...' in both models I believe.